# I believe I have done bad things in a past life can I fix my curse that causes people to turn against me what kind of Karma is this?

Tags: personal-practice, karma, past-lives

What kind of karma is it that causes people to suddenly go 180 on me when I seem to give 'too much' info about a certain point then they turn against me and give me the 'cold shoulder'? or have excuses to not be near me even if I currently haven't done anything wrong other then open up about myself?

Then I regret wishing to be born and I have had dreams that I may have had done bad things to  people in the past and went on the run instead of facing my trials as I'm always dreaming I'm escaping the police and often succeed in doing so leading me to think I ran from my crimes and haven't yet faced justice.

Is it even possible to have been a dictator in a past life and your put in this as punishment? When I die and go to the 'pearly gates' is a big arrest warrant going to be shown in my face instead how do I retcify this crap and heal myself?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Buddhism Q&A. I removed the parts of your question that were about Christianity and left the parts relevant to this site.

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, the fact that you came to this site, or even *thought* about Buddhism and karma means you actually inherited some very good karma from the past lives.

Having dreams about being chased by police means you have some guilt on your mind. Only you can tell what it is, but you must know - and it must be something obvious to you, it always works that way. If you just stop and look at it, you will see it.

People turning against you could mean one of two things: either you are saying careless things or you are in a wrong place. The only way to fix that is to be always real: true to yourself and true to others (without being either harsh or careless, it not easy but can be done).

In short, never regret that you were born. You have the same right to be here as these trees and stars, and just like they don't have to be something else to deserve to be here - you don't need to be someone else to deserve a place in the universe. If you can be always real, honest, and kind, things will work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe I have done bad things in a past life can I fix my curse that causes people to turn against me what kind of Karma is this?

Unless one's already attained the supernormal power of seeing one's previous lives, it won't do you any good trying speculate on what kind of evil deeds you did in your previous lives. Intead, it'd be very helpful and productive to start cultivating the Buddha's Dhamma in moral virtues, meditation, and insight/wisdom right now in this current life. It'll bring you great benefits not only in this present life but also many future lives to come. Regarding the various different results of Kamma, please refer to the [Salt Crystal Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than.html), [MN 135](https://suttacentral.net/mn135/en/bodhi) and [MN 136](https://suttacentral.net/mn136/en/thanissaro)

Answer (score 0):

Buddhism explains what right speech is. Generally, right speech keeps our life free from  social problems & conflicts. You should compare your habitual speech to Buddhist right speech. Right speech is explained at this [link](https://pintojukjun.blogspot.com/2011/09/right-speech-from-his-own-lips.html).

The above said, even if you practise right speech, there are always nasty people in the world who attack others, even for their goodness.

Buddhism teaches about many skills to help our life be free from problems, such as right speech, right ethics, associating with good people and avoiding bad friends.

Comment: How come some people verbally attack good, wholesome and helpful people?

Comment: Greed, hatred & delusion and ignorance

Answer (score -1):

One of the reason for miserable life is lack of good deeds.
The most important thing you need to do is read the scriptures daily and memorize the sutras , fast on every full moon and new moon, abstain from alcohol and non-veg food and donate to buddhist monks.

Wrong livelihood is another reason for such karma

Do good deeds and use it to overcome bad karma.

Comment: Which "sutras" are you suggesting be memorized? Thanks